# Why object's mutability is relevant to its Thread safe?

Tags: ios, multithreading

I am working on CoreImage on IOS, you guys know CIContext and CIImage are immutable so they can be shared on threads. The problem is i am not sure why objects' mutability is closely relevant to its thread safe.

I can guess the rough reason is to prevent multiple threads from do something on  a certain object at the same time. But can anybody provide some theoretical evidence or give a specific answer to it?

Comment: Also see Apple's [Thread Safety Summary](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/ThreadSafetySummary/ThreadSafetySummary.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000057i-CH12-SW1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct, mutable objects are not thread safe because multiple threads can write to that data at the same time. This is in contrast to reading data, an operation multiple threads can do simultaneously without causing problems. Immutable types can only be read.

However, when multiple threads are writing to the same data, these operations may interfere. For example, an `NSMutableArray` which two threads are editing could easily be corrupted. One thread is editing at one location, suddenly changing the memory the other thread was updating. iOS will use what is called an atomic operation for simple data types. What this means is that iOS requires the edit operation to fully finish before anything else can happen. This has an efficiency advantage over locks. Just Google about this stuff if you want to know more.

Comment: Can asyn operation on the same thread write to the same object simultaneously?

Comment: I didn't think so, but I can't say I know for sure

Comment: "iOS will use ... atomic operation for simple data types". Well, it can use atomic operations (e.g. if so instructed with atomic properties), but not necessarily so.

Answer (score 2):

Well, actually, you are right.

If you have an immutable objects, all you can do is to read data from them. And every thread will get the same data, since the object can not be changed.

When you have a mutable object, the problem is that (in general) read and write operations are not atomic. It means that they are not performed instantaneously, they take time. So they can overlap each other. Even if we have a single-core processor, it can switch between threads at arbitrary moments of time. Possible problems it might cause:

1) Two threads write at the same object simultaneously. In this case the object might become corrupted (for instance, half of data comes from the first thread, the other half – from the second, the result is unpredictable.

2) One thread writes the data, another one reads it. One problem is that thread might read already outdated data. Another one is that it might read a corrupted data (if the writing thread haven't finished writing yet).

Answer (score 1):

Take the example with an array of values. Let's say I'm doing some computation and I find the count of the array to be 4

```
var array = [1,2,3,4]
let count = array.count
```

Now maybe I want to loop through all the elements in the array, so I setup a loop that goes through index i<4 or something along those lines. So far so good.

This array is mutable though, so on a separate thread, I could easily remove an element. So perhaps I'm on thread 1 and I get the count to be 4, I perhaps start looping through the array. Now we switch to thread 2 and I remove an element, so now this same array has only 3 values in it. If I end up going back to thread 1 and I still assume I have 4 values while looping through the array, my program is going to crash when it tries to access the 4th element.

This is why immutability is desirable, it can guarantee some level of consistency across threads.

Comment: @user523234 What do you mean by a sync operation? If you mean synchronous then that depends on if you have another thread that is running with access to the array. If there is a background thread that has access to the exact same array, then there is nothing stopping it from changing that data structure (assuming there are no locks, etc)

Comment: @Carrl You're very welcome, concurrency will only become more important in the coming years and I think it's a great topic of discussion.

Comment: @user523234 Then it would be even more dangerous ;). If something is asynchronous, that means that it is happening concurrently on another thread or core. Async means that it doesn't have to carry out execution in order and can be happening when other operations are going. So the same idea applies if there are multiple async operations changing the same data structure.